# Fast directory clean-up with Perl

Tags: linux, perl, rm

I have a need to clean-up directory with millions of log files on my webserver. And I've found [this great article](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux) on how to do this. There is, however, a couple interesting things in that one-liner, which I am interested in.

Here's the Perl code I am interested in:

```
for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}
```

Runned with `perl -e 'code'`.

So, here are my questions:

1. the `for(<*>)` construction - I assume it iterates through the files in the current directory. But where does it store the iterator?
2. the `stat` and `unlink` functions expect at least one argument, I assume... But where is it?
3. why the result of calling `(stat)[9]` is compared to the result of calling `(unlink)`? And what does it results in?

Sorry, I am a no-perl-ish guy, thus I do not understand all those Perl abbreviations. That's why I am asking this question.

Thanks!

Comment: *I am a no-perl-ish guy*  I don't think the authors of the article really are either.  That looks like a line of code passed down from one admin to another that got slightly mangled along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That one liner takes many shortcuts:

1. The [`<*>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) is a special case of the diamond operator. You can't access an iterator object, like in other languages. Here, it calls the `glob` function. In list context it returns a list from all the results (which are either lines of a file, or, as in your case, contents of a diretory. The return value of that is passed to `for` which iterates over a list and aliases the values in `$_`. `$_` is the "default variable" for many functions…
2. Which brings us here. Many core functions default to `$_` with no argument. So do [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) and [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).
3. `(stat)[9]` means execute `stat` in list context and select the 10th result (indices start at zero, this is the modify time). (compare that to an array access like `$foo[9]`).

Comment: Nice! And what's about that `unlink` call result? Why is it compared to `stat[9]`???

Comment: I see no reason for that, unlink either returns `1` or the false value, depending on success. Maybe it's a really short way to execute both commands, but `;` should be as terse.

Comment: Using `stat` in void context is completely redundant as well. If there was a comparison of modification date, that would make sense. This would just delete all files. One might as well replace that with `unlink <*>`

Comment: There's no iterator. `<>` in list context returns all results (for both `readline` and `glob` versions).

Comment: @ikegami: The diamond is reffered to as iterator in some part of the docs. I already stated that you get all results in the third sentence.

Comment: @Patrick J. S., Of course they do; it's an iterator in scalar context. If you're calling the operator iterator, then your comment ("you can't access the iterator itself") makes no sense, since he is accessing (using) the operator. Either way, that comment is wrong.

Comment: @Patrick J. S., Of course they do; it's an iterator in scalar context. Sounds like you're saying you you're calling the operator iterator, but then your comment ("you can't access the iterator itself") makes no sense since he is accessing (using) the operator. Either way, that comment is wrong.

Comment: @ikegami: What I meant is, that there is no accessible iterator object, like in other languages. Do you think I should clarify that?

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for my $file (<*>) {
    my $mtime = (stat($file))[9];
    $mtime < unlink($file);
}
```

`<*>` can also be replaced with `glob "*"` which might be more readable.

The code will delete all files in the current directory. It will not delete directories.

Note that the last statement in the loop is completely redundant. If `use warnings` is in effect, it will give the warning:

```
Useless use of numeric lt (<) in void context
```

For this code to make sense, I would expect a comparison that actually matters, like comparing `$mtime` to some time to know which logs are old, e.g.:

```
if ($mtime < $oldtime) {
    unlink $file or die "Cannot unlink $file: $!";
}
```

Note also that it might be prudent to check for failure when deleting files.

Comment: **<*> can also be replaced with glob "*" which might be more readable.** You should use glob in your answer--because it's the <*> that makes it look like a file handle is involved.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. the for(<*>) construction - I assume it iterates through the files in the current directory. But where does it store the iterator?

for-loops can be used to iterate over arrays/lists, so if `<*>` produces a list, then your code is just a run of the mill for loop.  As it turns out `<*>` is another way to spell glob(), which is sort of like a regex for retrieving file names, and glob() returns a list in *list context*--which is the context a for loop provides.  See: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html.

<del>Note that the single quotes keep the shell from expanding the `*`, which would prevent perl from ever seeing it.</del>

Comment: The shell would not interpolate `*`.

Comment: @TLP, Me ignorant. :(